# How can I replace a number for an increasing number for each line using sed?

Tags: text, sed, replace

I got a file with the following text -

observ1
observ1
observ1
observ1
observ1

What I need is a sed command that replace it to -

observ1
observ2
observ3
observ4
observ5

Or a sed command to add observ# in the beginning of each line for example -
file 1.txt -
hi
bye
see
you
soon

After said sed command -

observ1,hi
observ2,bye
observ3,see
observ4,you
observ5,soon

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `sed` is not suited for arithmetic tasks. You can use `awk` or `perl` instead. If you know the number of lines, you can also use a combination of `printf+paste`

Comment: I tried all kinds of combinations with awk but I was looking for one command to add an increasing wordN to the beginning of each line. I was able to create a new file with the output of sed '=' and the line numbers in the beginning but I would need another sed command to delete the space and add the observ word in the beginning of the line. Was hoping for a one liner with sed.

Comment: Not sure this counts as arithmetic task though since there's no manipulation of the numbers. If the sed command could place the number of the line including the word before it, that would do.

Comment: yeah, the sed command `=` gives line numbers but manipulating it the way you want for this problem requires you to jump through hoops.. anyway, please add some of the commands you tried to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4 steps :

```
sed = a.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/,/' | sed 's/^/observ/' > b.txt
```

1. numbering lines of the file
2. add number + ',' at each line
3. add prefix 'observ' at each line
4. print result in new file

Comment: Thanks a lot Emerald!!! Appreciate it!